# Failing to copy one cell to another cell using Destination Copy

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, runtime-error

```
Range("A1").Copy (Range("E5"))
```

That fails, but if I explicitly define the destination range as a Destination, like the following, it works.

```
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("E5")
```

If I give a Worksheet reference for my destination, like the following, it also works:

```
Range("A1").Copy (Worksheets("Sheet1).Range("E5"))
```

---

Why is the simplest form, not working, and giving me

> Runtime Error 1004: "Copy method of Range class failed"

instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
Range("A1").Copy (Range("E5"))
```

and

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("E5")
```

is that the first one converts the `ByRef` argument into `ByVal` while the second does not. The parenthesis here stands for a conversion and not for what you expected.

Note that you must only use the parenthesis when you use a function (that returns a value) but **not** when using a procedure.

Example

```
a = MyFunction(Parameter1, Parameter2)   'correct with parenthesis
MyProcedure Parameter1, Parameter2       'correct w/o parenthesis

a = MyFunction Parameter1, Parameter2    'it will error
MyProcedure(Parameter1, Parameter2)      'it will error
```

now with only one parameter

```
a = MyFunction(Parameter1)   'correct with parenthesis
MyProcedure Parameter1       'correct w/o parenthesis

a = MyFunction Parameter1    'it will error
MyProcedure (Parameter1)     'it will NOT error but convert ByRef into ByVal !!!
```

The last line of the above example does something completly different than you expected. You can notice the extra space between the procedure name and the parenthesis. And it is the same like the following syntax

```
a = MyFunction((Parameter1), (Parameter2))   'convert ByRef into ByVal
MyProcedure (Parameter1), (Parameter2)       'convert ByRef into ByVal
```

So we can note down:

- If a function returns a value that we want to write into a variable:
  You **must** use parenthesis: `a = MyFunction(Parameter1)`
- If a procedure (or function) does **not** return a value then:
  You **must not** use parenthesis: `MyProcedure Parameter1`

Comment: Thanks! So, why does my last line of code, with the Worksheet noted, work, even though it's in brackets?

Comment: @Malady Actually I cannot explain why it worked (maybe accidentally). But the syntax is wrong too (it should be without the parenthesis too). Anyway it is a good practice to **always** specify a worksheet for every `Range` and `Cells` object. It makes your code much more reliable and stops Excel guessing which sheet you meant to use.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will, then ask about the inconsistency in another question...

Comment: Made the question, if you wanna look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996540/how-does-byref-to-byval-by-parentheses-work-when-the-byref-is-a-range-with-a-wo

Answer (score 0):

you have to eliminate brackets

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("E5")
```

Comment: Expanding why that works would help, but also make it a dupe of the above... So, maybe delete? I dunno.