# How does ByRef to ByVal by parentheses work, when the ByRef is a Range with a Worksheet reference?

Tags: excel, vba

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58872378/4592583), parentheses in VBA function arguments turn ByRefs to ByVals,

And Range Copy, whose only available variable is a Destination Range, needs that destination to be a ByRef?

So, how is this working? Shouldn't the Cell referenced with Worksheet Specified, being a ByRef in parentheses, be converted into a ByVal and cause the Copy to fail?

```
Range("A1").Copy (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5"))
```

Comment: Who says it needs that destination passed `ByRef`?

Comment: @Rory - That's what I was getting from this answer to my previous question. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864512/failing-to-copy-one-cell-to-another-cell-using-destination-copy/58872378#58872378

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. It requires a `Range` object, that much is true. Check the results of: `typename((sheets(1).range("A1")))` versus `typename((range("A1")))` and you should see why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Rory - Range vs. String... So my initial question's Accepted Answer is full of true things, but got the explanation of my issue wrong?

Comment: Going to mark this as duplicate: two candidates that the OP would be interested in reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56692769/9101981 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45747604/9101981. Pity I can't add two duplicates in the one flag, because both posts have comprehensive answers (by Mathieu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: Usage of parentheses for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692769/vba-usage-of-parentheses-for-a-method)

Comment: @AJD - I dunno... All those questions have so much specific-ness I can't tell if they answer my question or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Apparently, parentheses in VBA function arguments turn ByRefs to ByVals.

Well, no, not exactly.

The parentheses make the parameter into an *expression* that gets evaluated and then its *value* is passed on.

You will see this when you call a Sub that has two parameters:

```
mySub 1, 2       ' this is OK
mySub (1, 2)     ' this makes VB complain
```

The second example makes from `(1, 2)` an expression; however, the expression is *invalid* so VB will complain.

If you call a function without using the return value, then *do not use parentheses*:

```
myFunction 1, 2        ' this is OK
myFunction (1, 2)      ' this is an error
i = myFunction (1, 2)  ' here the parentheses are required.
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things:

1. Copy doesn't care how you pass the destination `Range`, as long as it's a `Range` object. So, for example:

   `Range("A1").Copy ByVal Range("B1")`

will work just fine.

2. The parentheses try to *evaluate* what's inside them as an expression. So in your first case, what you actually end up passing is the **value** of the range, not the range itself. The weird part is actually that the evaluation returns the `Range` object properly when you add the `Worksheets()` call. This has *something* to do with late binding as best I can tell because that Worksheets call returns an `Object` type, not a `Worksheet`. If you were to use a worksheet code name (e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1")`) instead, you'd have the same problem as you had originally. Really need someone like Mathieu to explain the inner workings of that.

Comment: A helpful explanation; good point to compare with references via `CodeName` +1 :-)