# how can i pass a optional value to a sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a sub. Maybe I should do it as a function because I will be calling this many different times.

But for now it's a sub, unless that is why it's not working?

I'm passing two sheet names via macro, to show one sheet, then hide the previous one.

However, I get the error ["Expected  = "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkDMz.jpg)

Code is below, any ideas?

```
Sub setupToFront()

    showsheet ("Status","Setup")

End Sub


Sub showsheet(mySheet As String, Optional ByVal hidesheet As Variant)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(mySheet)

ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
ws.Activate

If IsMissing(hidesheet) Then
    'nothing, optional val not used
Else
    Worksheets(CStr(hidesheet)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Drop the parentheses: `showsheet "Status","Setup"`

Comment: Remove the brackets: `showsheet "Status", "Setup"`

Comment: The parentheses indicates you are trying to return something, there is no variable to the left of the sub call so it is yelling, even though there is no return in ```showsheet```.

Comment: Or precede with “call” then you can use the parenthesis.

Comment: The parentheses in `showsheet ("Status","Setup")` induce VBA to **evaluate** what's inside them as a supposed expression; furthermore this supposed expression is regarded here as the procedure's *first* argument resulting in a compile error as `("Status","Setup")` can't be evaluated with success. C.f. [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996540/how-does-byref-to-byval-by-parentheses-work-when-the-byref-is-a-range-with-a-wo?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692769/vba-usage-of-parentheses-for-a-method?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expecting to return a result as if you were using a function hence it expected the =.

Just `showsheet "Status", "Setup"` will work fine to run a sub.